# Trying to extract xml element using python 2.7

Tags: python, xml-parsing

I am trying to extract the name elements under the sequence in xml files. I have pasted in the top of a sample xml to illustrate. With this I want to get the text from 01 Interview_been successful through mentorship and write it to a file. There are multiple sequence tags in the xml and I am trying to figure out how to go through it and extract it. I have tried to figure out how to use xml.etree and xml.dom.minidom but I can't seem to wrap my brain around it. I was able to get all of the id values from the sequence tags but not the name elements. I'm pasting in my code before the xml.

```
from xml.etree import ElementTree


file = open("xmldump.txt", "r")
filedata = file.read()
file.close()

with open('test.xml', 'rt') as f:
    tree = ElementTree.parse(f)

for node in tree.iter('name'):
    sequenceid = node.attrib.get('name')
    print '  %s' % (sequenceid)
    newLine = sequenceid + "\n"
    file = open("xmldump.txt", "w")
    file.write(newLine)
    file.close()
```

Here is the XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE xmeml>
<xmeml version="5">
<bin>
<uuid>0F5D72FA-54E4-4DE8-81D7-CC33F5C43836</uuid>
<updatebehavior>add</updatebehavior>
<name>Logged</name>
<children>
    <sequence id="01 Interview_been successful through mentorship">
        <uuid>12FB944D-83EA-4527-9A54-2130A42E3A06</uuid>
        <updatebehavior>add</updatebehavior>
        <name>01 Interview_been successful through mentorship</name>
        <duration>1195</duration>
        <rate>
            <ntsc>TRUE</ntsc>
            <timebase>24</timebase>
        </rate>
        <timecode>
```

Comment: That's not a valid XML document. `timecode`, `sequence`, etc. nodes are opened and never closed. If you're actually trying to parse a fragment, you cannot use a DOM parser (like `minidom` or `ElementTree.parse`) for that; you need an iterative parser (like `ElementTree.iterparse`) or a SAX parser. If you're trying to parse a real document, please give us a real document.

Comment: Also, you're trying to get the `name` attribute of every `name` node. Your code does that, but in your sample XML, neither `name` node has a `name` attribute, or any attributes at all. Are you trying to get the inner text of the `name` nodes? Or… what? And why would you call whatever it is you're getting a `sequenceid`?

Comment: He did say "I have pasted in the top of a sample xml to illustrate". I think that's just a partial, his file probably is valid xml

Comment: @entropy: It's the OP's responsibility to provide an [sscce](http://sscce.org), not our job to guess what he might mean. Maybe that sample followed by 5 closing tags demonstrates his problem, but how do we know that without guessing and then hoping?

Comment: @abarnert I fully agree that it's his responsibility. I was just pointing out the fact that he said this was the "top of a sample" which probably means it's a partial file and he chose an unfortunate place to cut it.

Comment: OP, the string "01 Interview_been successful through mentorship" appears twice in the sample XML fragment you provided; once as the value of `id` attribute of the `sequence` node and once as the text inside the `name` node. This makes it a confusing example. Which one of these are you attempting to extract? Please consider being more specific in your question and maybe updating the example.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, I'm not sure if you want the "id" attribute or the name tag(your code is confusing, it tries to extract a "name" attribute out of the "sequence" tag, but that tag only has an "id" attribute). Below is code that extract both, should help you get started on figuring out how ElementTree works

```
from xml.etree import ElementTree

with open('test.xml', 'rt') as f:
    tree = ElementTree.parse(f)

for node in tree.iter('sequence'):
    sequenceid = node.attrib.get('id')
    name = node.findtext('name')
```

Comment: Thank you so much. You solved my problem and helped me complete my program. The xml I was referencing is a huge export from Final Cut Pro so I was afraid to post anything beyond showing the tag I wanted to grab. Thank you again for your kindness and understanding.

Comment: My pleasure :-) you should mark the answer as accepted though. Just press the check mark next to it.